# Is it possible to make a shorter representation for an equation?

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis, functions

I have an equation as follows:
$$
f_{n,k_1,1}=
\begin{cases}
0,&\text{$k_1>n_1,$ or $n-k_1>n_2$}\\
\frac{\binom{n_1}{k_1}\binom{n_2}{n-k_1}}{\binom{n_1+n_2}{n}}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

And

$$
f_{n,k_1,2}=
\begin{cases}
0,&\text{$k_1>n_2,$ or $n-k_1>n_1$}\\
\frac{\binom{n_2}{k_1}\binom{n_1}{n-k_1}}{\binom{n_1+n_2}{n}}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The different between $f_{n,k_1,1}, f_{n,k_1,2}$ is that just changes position of $n_1,n_2$ in the bionominal term. Hence, I want to make $f_{n,k_1,1}, f_{n,k_1,2}$ more shorter as

$$
f_{n,k_1,i}=
\begin{cases}
...\\
...
\end{cases}
$$

where $i={1,2}$. Is it possible to make it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could say

$$f_{n,k_1,i} = \begin{cases}0, & k_1>n_i \text{ or } n-k_1 > n_{\bar i}\\
\displaystyle{\frac{{n_i\choose k_1}{n_{\bar i}\choose n-k_1}}{{n_1+n_2\choose n}}},& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

and explain that $\bar 1=2$ and $\bar 2=1$.

Comment: but your bionominal term does not change and the invert way look so complex

Comment: @user2938494 It does now.